# What does this operator mean? /=

Tags: c, operators

I have just come across some code with the line:

```
n /= 10;
```

I assumed it was a typo and removed the `/` to make it `n = 10`, but the program no longer works.

Never seen this sort of operator before, anybody know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/=` is a shorthand operator.

```
a /= b
```

is equivalent to

```
c = a/b;
a = c;
```

Comment: Or simply `a = a / b;`

Comment: @FredLarson Absolutely. Just elaborated to remove any more confusions.:)

Answer (score 3):

The `/=` is one of the shorthand operators.

A shorthand operator is a concise way to express something that is already available in a programming language.

They are:

- `+=` (E.g.: `x += 4;` is equivalent to `x = x + 4;`)
- `-=` (E.g.: `x -= 4;` is equivalent to `x = x - 4;`)
- `*=` (E.g.: `x *= 4;` is equivalent to `x = x * 4;`)
- `/=` (E.g.: `x *= 4;` is equivalent to `x = x / 4;`)
- `%=` (E.g.: `x %= 4;` is equivalent to `x = x % 4;`)

Comment: Maybe "concise" better word than "shorter".

Comment: @FiddlingBits you are right! Sorry, I'm not a native English speaker. Just edited.

Comment: You're English is perfect!

Answer (score 2):

`n /= 10` is taking the value of `n`, dividing it by `10` and reassigning that value to `n`.

It's just shorthand for `n = (n / 10)` just like `n++` is `n = n + 1`.

Answer (score 2):

It is the same as

```
n = n/10 ;
```

You can use this form also with other operators (+, -, %,...).

The case n+=1 (n-=1) can also be written as `n++` (increase n by 1) or `++n`.

Answer (score -1):

It simply means `n = n/10`. The same form can be used with other operators too.

Comment: How is this any different from the 4 answers posted last year that already say this?