# In the code shown below, what does the "average /=5.0" mean?

Tags: c

In the code shown below, what does average /= 5.0 mean? What is it implying? This is for `C` language. I am using this code to find out the average marks obtained in 2 subjects denoted as i and j.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int grades[2][5];
    float average;
    int i;
    int j;

    grades[0][0]=98;
    grades[0][1]=98;
    grades[0][2]=98;
    grades[0][3]=88;
    grades[0][4]=98;

    grades[1][0]=98;
    grades[1][1]=98;
    grades[1][2]=98;
    grades[1][3]=98;
    grades[1][4]=98;

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i ++)
    {
        average = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j ++)
        {
            average += grades[i][j];
        }
        average /= 5.0;

        printf("The average of subject %d is: %.2f\n", i, average);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Compound assignment operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Compound_assignment_operators)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does this operator mean? /=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049868/what-does-this-operator-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a shortcut for `average = average / 5.0;`.

You can do the same for many operations:

- `average += 5.0;` is the same as `average = average + 5.0;`
- `average -= 5.0;` is the same as `average = average - 5.0;`
- `average *= 5.0;` is the same as `average = average * 5.0;`

These are called [compound assignment operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Compound_assignment_operators).